# PermitAll() not working, Unauthorized 401. Spring security config

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have multiple entry points. One of them must be protected by a filter, the rest are completely open.

```
/data/** - filter protected
/callback/** - permitAll
/save/**     - permitAll
/oauth/**    - permitAll
```

My application is missing users, roles and database. I only need to check JWT that it is signed with the correct private key.
So, i use:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude= {UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

I tried many combinations, it either requires everyone to check the JWT for all input points using a filter, or 401 errors. Role anonymous set because there was a 403 error if set .authenticated()

Pls help me..

My configuration adapter:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DataSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new JwtAuthFilter();
    }

  @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and()
             
                .csrf().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
               
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/data/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_ANONYMOUS")
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), AuthorizationFilter.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
               
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web){
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/oauth/**","/callback/**","/save/**");
    }
}
```

My Filter:

```
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class JwtAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Value("${auth-service.secret-key}")
    private String jwtSecret;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthFilter.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @Nullable HttpServletRequest request,
            @Nullable HttpServletResponse response,
            @Nullable FilterChain filterChain
    )
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        assert request != null;

        String jwt = parseJwt(request);
        if (jwt!=null && validateToken(jwt) ) {
            assert filterChain != null;
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            assert response != null;
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }
    private String parseJwt(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String headerAuth = request.getHeader("Authorization");

        if (StringUtils.hasText(headerAuth) && headerAuth.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return headerAuth.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private boolean validateToken(String authToken) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(jwtSecret).parseClaimsJws(authToken);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error: {}", e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Call http://localhost:9088/oauth/test

Response:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-03-30T07:52:22.692+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/oauth/test"
}
```

TRACE:

```
2023-03-30 11:52:22.662 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/oauth/**'], Filters=[]] (1/3)
2023-03-30 11:52:22.662 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Ant [pattern='/callback/**'], Filters=[]] (2/3)
2023-03-30 11:52:22.663 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6e807e2, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@7767bd4e, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1537e43, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@6c995c5d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@433ef204, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@165614f5, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@203b953c, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1304e0d7, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@9a9aa68, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@389a5022, com.test.authorization.configuration.security.JwtAuthFilter@1fdca564]] (3/3)
2023-03-30 11:52:22.663 DEBUG 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2023-03-30 11:52:22.664 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (1/11)
2023-03-30 11:52:22.664 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextPersistenceFilter (2/11)
2023-03-30 11:52:22.665 DEBUG 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Set SecurityContextHolder to empty SecurityContext
2023-03-30 11:52:22.665 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (3/11)
2023-03-30 11:52:22.665 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CorsFilter (4/11)
2023-03-30 11:52:22.665 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (5/11)
2023-03-30 11:52:22.665 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (6/11)
2023-03-30 11:52:22.666 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (7/11)
2023-03-30 11:52:22.667 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-03-30 11:52:22.667 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (8/11)
2023-03-30 11:52:22.667 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (9/11)
2023-03-30 11:52:22.667 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking FilterSecurityInterceptor (10/11)
2023-03-30 11:52:22.668 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/data/**'] - [hasAuthority('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')] (1/2)
2023-03-30 11:52:22.668 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Did not re-authenticate AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] before authorizing
2023-03-30 11:52:22.668 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorizing filter invocation [GET /error] with attributes [permitAll]
2023-03-30 11:52:22.672 DEBUG 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorized filter invocation [GET /error] with attributes [permitAll]
2023-03-30 11:52:22.672 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Did not switch RunAs authentication since RunAsManager returned null
2023-03-30 11:52:22.672 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking JwtAuthFilter (11/11)
2023-03-30 11:52:22.673 DEBUG 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /error
2023-03-30 11:52:22.676 TRACE 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] edFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/data/**'] - [hasAuthority('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')] (1/2)
2023-03-30 11:52:22.732 DEBUG 6744 --- [nio-9092-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
```

i just need to close /data/** , the rest are open.

Comment: You can add permit to concrete address like this .antMatchers("/api/public").permitAll() or try to disable csrf for HttpSecurity like this .csrf().disable();

Comment: @Yeras_QazaQ I have everything open to specific endpoints. And csrf disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your Filter is always executing, even before the non authenticated calls.

To solve it you have to say which request to handle by your Filter.
For that you have two options:

1. add the `shouldNotFilter` method to your `JwtAuthFilter`

   ```
   @Override
   protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
     return !request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/data/");
   }
   ```
2. simply add the following if condition to the beginning of your `JwtAuthFilter.doFilterInternal`:

   ```
   if (!request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/data/")) {
       filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
       return;
   }
   ```

Exactly the same issue has been discussed in the following video at 1:11:11 timestamp: [Spring Security, demystified by Daniel Garnier Moiroux](https://youtu.be/iJ2muJniikY?t=4271)